# Conexion de base de datos mysql con laravel para proyecto de ecommerce

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

He estado desarrollando una aplicacion web para un trabajo final de una materia en la carrera desarrollo de software, me ha tocado el tema de una tienda en linea por lo que la he estado desarrollando y tengo que usar el CRUD de forma obligatoria para los productos, es decir que tengo que llamar desde la base de datos toda la informacion de dichos productos, he creado el modelo:

```php
<?php 
namespace App\Models;  
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class producto extends Model { 
    use HasFactory; 
    protected $table = 'productos'; 
}
```

y tambien el controlador:

```php
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers; 
use App\Models\Producto; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductoController extends Controller { 
    public function producto($id) { 
        $producto = Producto::findOrFail($id); 
        return view('producto')->with('producto', $producto);
    }
}
```

Por supuesto que tambien he hecho la conexion en el documento `.env` de laravel, por lo que al momento de hacer las migraciones me ha funcionado a la perfeccion, al usar tambien el comando `php artisan migrate:fresh` se modificó la base de datos, lo que dice que si esta funcionando.

AHORA VIENE EL INCONVENIENTE: he agregado datos a la base de datos, pero al momento de usar o llamar ciertos datos de la tabla como por ejemplo `{{$producto->nombre}}` para que el nombre de un `h1` cambie al nombre que tengo en la base de datos, al agregarlo al campo del `h1` del template que tengo en html y al acceder desde el `localhost` a esa pagina, dice que la variable `$producto` no esta definida.

He intentado de todo pero sigue sin funcionar, he buscado documentacion, videos e incluso e intentado con chat gpt pero tampoco funciona, llevo 5 horas intentando solucionar y no he llegado a ninguna solucion. Cabe aclarar que estoy usando el metodo en el controlador para que no tome todos los datos de la tabla si no que use uno por uno con el id. Agradezco cualquier ayuda o consejo, he desplegado el codigo que creo necesario para poder que ustedes lo veean y puedan entender como lo tengo armado.

Comment: Creo que a toda tu explicacion, le falto especificar donde es que estas usando esos valores... o como los estas usando...

Comment: Por supuesto que no debe funcionar, en tu controlador estás llamando a un modelo que no existe: `$producto = Producto::findOrFail($id);` con el namespace `use App\Models\Producto;`. Sin embargo el modelo se llama **producto**, no corresponden los nombres del modelo con la llamada que haces en el controlador.

Comment: @williamrb te recomiendo arriesgarte y publicar una respuesta cuando estes seguro del problema y de la solución. Además podrías aportar sugerencias de tu conocimiento de este modo ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos ver que dentro del modelo estás llamando a la taba `productos`.

```
class producto extends Model { 
    use HasFactory; 
    protected $table = 'productos'; 
}
```

Pero dentro del controlador estás haciendo algo diferente.

```
class ProductoController extends Controller { 
    public function producto($id) { 
        $producto = Producto::findOrFail($id); 
        return view('producto')->with('producto', $producto);
    }
}
```

1. Estás retornando la VISTA `producto`. (y nosotros nisiquiera sabemos si dicha vista existe)
2. De la mano con lo anterior, no estás validando excepciones de ninguna forma, es decir, si no encuentra la vista por ejemplo, no está dandote un error detallado a ti para saberlo. O en el caso del producto tampoco hay un manejo apropiado en ciertos casos.
3. La clase `producto` debería ir mayúsculas, justo como la otra clase. Cambiala por `Producto`.
4. La función `producto` recomiendo aportarle un nombre más descriptivo, para que sepas realmente que hace y que esta misma no se confunda con la clase, la tabla, etc. Por ejemplo `buscarProductoPorID`.

En resumen, te recomiendo probar lo siguiente:

```
public function buscarProductoPorId($id) { 
    try {
        $producto = Producto::findOrFail($id);
        if ($producto) { //Validamos que el producto obtenga algo
            return view('producto')->with('producto', $producto);
        } else {
            //Agregar algún manejo de errores
        }
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        //Agregar algún manejo de errores
    }
}
```

Otras sugerencias:

- Validar que el modelo sea correcto
- Validar `$id` para corroborar que sea una ID válida.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!! he revisado minuciosamente tu respuesta y he verificado en mi codigo, ya pude solucionarlo, arreglando el controlado, el modelo y las rutas en web.php, ahora ya funciona de forma correcta!